# How do I test stripe and my controller effectively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stripe-payments

I have the following models:
`subscription`, `user`, and `events`

- A `user` `has_one` `subscription`
- A `subscription` `belongs_to` a `user`
- A `user` `has_many` `events`
- An `event` `belongs_to` a `user`

So far I have been able to successfully create acceptance tests using Capybara and RSpec. This allows me to 'upgrade' a users account (which adds a different role). I've also been able to do an acceptance test where the user cancels their subscription and ensure their roles are removed.

However, now I want to ensure that any of the user's open events are cancelled. This is where I'm getting stuck. Actually, I didn't even get this far because I ran in to trouble trying to even destroy a subscription.

So, I created a controller spec called `subscriptions_controller_spec.rb`. In this spec, there is a test to ensure the `destroy` action works as expected. This is failing because in my controller it goes to retrieve the customer and subscription, which doesn't exist, and returns an `Stripe::InvalidRequestError`.

In order to get around this, I tried to use `stripe-ruby-mock` to mock the stripe servers. However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use this in a controller spec and I got really confused. Below is my controller and my controller spec. Any advice on how I should attack this would be really appreciated.

`subscriptions_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SubscriptionsController, :type => :controller do

  let(:stripe_helper) { StripeMock.create_test_helper }
  before { StripeMock.start }
  after { StripeMock.stop }

  # ... omitted 

  describe 'DELETE destroy' do
    before :each do
      sign_in_trainer
      @subscription = create(:subscription, user: subject.current_user)
      plan = stripe_helper.create_plan(:id => 'Standard')
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
                                            email: 'johnny@appleseed.com',
                                            source: stripe_helper.generate_card_token,
                                            plan: 'Standard'
                                        })
      @subscription.customer_id = customer.id
      @subscription.stripe_sub_id = customer.subscriptions.data.first.id
    end

    it 'destroys the requested subscription' do
      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => @subscription.to_param}
      }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(-1)
    end

    # ... omitted

  end
end
```

And `subscriptions_controller.rb`

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subscription, only: [:update, :destroy]

  # ... ommitted

  # DELETE /cancel-subscriptions/1
  def destroy
    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@subscription.customer_id)
      customer.subscriptions.retrieve(@subscription.stripe_sub_id).delete
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      # User's card was declined for many magnitude of reasons
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path, alert: 'There was a problem cancelling your subscription' and return
    rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e
      # Stripe network issues
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path, alert: 'Network issue. Please try again later' and return
    rescue Stripe::APIError => e
      # Stripe network issues
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path, alert: 'Network issue. Please try again later' and return
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      # This is something that we screwed up in our programming. This should literally never happen.
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path, alert: 'There was a problem cancelling your subscription.' and return
    rescue => e
      logger.error e.message
      logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path, alert: 'There was a problem cancelling your subscription.' and return
    end

    if current_user.events
      @events = current_user.events
      @events.open.each do |event|
        event.cancel
      end
    end

    current_user.remove_role 'trainer'
    current_user.add_role 'user'
    current_user.save
    @subscription.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_dashboard_path, notice: 'Subscription cancelled. All your open events have been cancelled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_subscription
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def subscription_params
    params[:subscription]
  end
end
```

Comment: where's the part where you mock stripe?

Comment: I've omitted it because I was very confused. I can re-add it if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, please add it - sometimes we can just see what the bug was and fix it ;)

Comment: Of course you could always just mock Stripe with simple mocks like `expect(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:retreive).and_raise(Stripe::CardError)` or the like...

Comment: I think what I might also need to do is also add my Factories to the question. Damn this is a complex one to ask effectively over SO.

Comment: BTW - separately to getting this working - you have a *lot* going on in your controller. I agree with the idea that it might be time to move this out into a service class (which you can test independently - and then just mock in this controller spec to Just Work)

Comment: I've added the mock stuff. You'll see now how I managed to confuse myself

Comment: interesting. I don't think I've used StripeMock before (and we use Stripe too), so I can't say whether this is how it's supposed to be used or not... I don't know why but I always get an iffy feeling about something that needs both before and after...  the shadow of being burnt in the past I suspect ;)

Comment: Here's the GitHub: https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock - Honestly I have no idea if this is how it is supposed to be used either. First major rails site, first use of Stripe. I am in deep!

Comment: Looks interesting. Certainly worth looking into. Doesn't look like you're doing anything differently to what is expected. They have a chat-server here: https://gitter.im/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock if you want to ask them about it.

Comment: In case you're interested @TarynEast I followed ridget's example and moved it in to a service object. It all works but now I will refactor the tests to accomodate the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've kind of already hit the nail on the head here, the fact that it's hard to test in a controller spec indicates that it might be a good time to consider moving the behaviour to a service class.

What i'd do is setup an integration test to use as your feedback loop, then refactor and get back to green. Once you've done that, start refactoring your service class and building on your specs from there.

Comment: Thanks Tom... I literally have no idea where to start in moving it to a service class though. Can you recommend any materials online that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: patrick, sorry mate, service class is just a fancy term for a class dedicated to the task. ping me on my work email if you want to pair on this, in the meantime I think Taryns answer should assist you to get those tests passing in the short term.

Comment: Can't say I've actually read/used this one, but google indicates this - and seem to even use Stripe as an example... https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: ridget, what's your work email?
@TarynEast - that looks promising. Thanks

Comment: @TarynEast's post is definitely an awesome example, patrick I've pinged you on github with my contact details.

Comment: I've found this post helpful on refactoring complex ruby apps:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 1):

Does simply mocking out Stripe not work eg:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SubscriptionsController, :type => :controller do

  # ... omitted 

  describe 'DELETE destroy' do
    before :each do
      sign_in_trainer
      @subscription = create(:subscription, user: subject.current_user)
    end

    it 'destroys the requested subscription' do
      # just mock stripe to pass back the customer you expect - as though it Just Works
      expect(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:retreive).and_return(subscription.customer)

      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => @subscription.to_param}
      }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(-1)
    end


    it 'does not destroy it if we got a card error' do
      # likewise you can mock up what happens when an error is raised
      expect(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:retreive).and_raise(Stripe::CardError)

      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => @subscription.to_param}
      }.not_to change(Subscription, :count)
    end
    # ... omitted

  end
end
```

Comment: OK Thanks for this. I'm going to give it a go this afternoon.